# How to run Jenkins build steps in a loop from csv file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm trying to create a job that will run a certain flow multiple times, each time with different parameters on multiple nodes in parallel. 
I have a csv file, on which each line contains the requested parameters for a run. 
I tried using multi configuration job, and I read about the dynamic axis, but I don't quite understand how to use it with the data from my csv file. 
I also saw build flow and workflow plugins, but again, I couldn't understand how to use it with my csv file.

I'd appreciate if anyone can give me ideas how to solve this.

Thanks in advance,

Sivan

Answer (score 2):

Beneath a solution without eachLine closure (works in Jenkins ver. 2.89.3).
Some closures like eachLine still seem to be broken in Jenkins.

```
def nodes = [:]

readFile("input.csv").split('\n').eachWithIndex { line, index ->
    def params = line.split(',')
    nodes[name] = {
        // ...
    }
```

If you don't need the counter, you can use 'each' instead

```
readFile("input.csv").split('\n').each { line -> ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the workflow plugin you could read the file, parse the contents with standard groovy then set up your nodes - something like

```
def nodes = [:]
readFile("myfile.csv").eachLine { line, count ->
    def params = line.split(',')
    nodes["line${count}"] = {
        node {
             // do stuff
        }
    }
}
parallel nodes
```

if you dont need the count variable you could use splitEachLine instead

```
def nodes = [:]
readFile("abc.csv").splitEachLine(/,/) { runName, param2, p3 ->
    nodes[runName] = {
         // dostuff with param2, p3
    }
}
```

Comment: As written that will not currently work due to [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481), so you would need to perhaps split on newlines and then use a C-style `for` loop.

Comment: @JesseGlick Can you please provide an example of this? I am trying to do the same thing.